# Toggle class on div when clicking

Tags: jquery

I have 2 div called "button" with another div inside. I would like to change visibility when clicked:

```
<div class="button"> 
    <div class="content"> 1 </div>
</div>

<div class="button"> 
    <div class="content"> 2 </div>
</div>
```

Im applying class="show" with display: block to show "content" when clicking it.

But how do i remove class='show' from an already visible div and make a new div visible when clicked?

Should be something like this:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.content').removeClass('show'); 
    // This line wont work  - only here to show what im trying to accomplish.. 
    $(this).(".content").addClass("show");
});
```

Comment: Your selector is selecting an element with `id="button"`. No such element exists in your sample HTML.

Comment: ok - class off course - question is edited from my own original code

Comment: `$(this).(".content")` is improper syntax. Use `$(this).find(".content")` instead.

Comment: You do realise that 3rd line is rubbish? Only here to show what im trying to do..

Comment: You do realize I'm not a mind-reader and only know what you are trying to do by what you are showing to us? Do what I suggested and it will work. ***Next time you want help, post your actual code.*** And don't be a smart ass when people offer help for free.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - should have cleaned my code and written the comment for the 3line in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find` and `toggleClass`

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(".content").removeClass("show");
    $(this).find(".content").toggleClass("show");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem. You forgot to hide all of the ".content" nodes first :P

Comment: You get my seal of approval!

Comment: @KennethHayes -- Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your solution works - i needed a few hours of sleep..!